# How to get switch on/off status for switches created and added in a cycle to the stackView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating `UIStackView` and in a cycle creating some amount of `UILabel` and `UISwitch` pairs that are added to `UIStackView`. How now I can get the status of `UISwitch` is it **ON** or **OFF**?

```
 func addAnswrsToTheStack(using answers: [Answer]){
    createHorizontalStackView()
    horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(questionProgressView)

    var questionSwitch: UISwitch!

 for answer in answers {
    createHorizontalStackView()
    let label: UILabel = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.text = answer.text

    horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

    questionSwitch = UISwitch()

    questionSwitch.isOn = false
    horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(questionSwitch)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
for (index,answer) in answers.enumerated() { 
  ....
  questionSwitch = UISwitch() 
  questionSwitch.tag = index
  questionSwitch.isOn = false
  questionSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged), for:.valueChanged)
}

@objc func switchChanged(_ mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    let value = mySwitch.isOn
    print(mySwitch.tag , value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the value of a `UISwitch` the same way you set it, by calling `isOn`. You can loop through all the views in your stackView, check if the view is a switch with

```
for view in horizontalStackView.arrangedSubviews {
    if view is UISwitch {
      // check the value here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't know the state state of a switch for each answer since you only create the switch, but you don't save that association. A clean way would be a wrappertype that has a Answer and a UISwitch. But let's do it without for now.
You need return a map that tells you what switch is related what question.
 The type [Answer:UISwitch] will work and thats it. You now can look up each Switch and its state for an Answer.

```
func addAnswrsToTheStack(using answers: [Answer]) -> [Answer:UISwitch] {
        createHorizontalStackView()
        horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(questionProgressView)

        var questionSwitch: UISwitch!

        var switchMap = [Answer:UISwitch]()

        for answer in answers {
            createHorizontalStackView()
            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            label.textAlignment = .left
            label.text = answer.text

            horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

            questionSwitch = UISwitch()

            questionSwitch.isOn = false
            switchMap[Answer] = questionSwitch
            horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(questionSwitch)
        }
        return switchMap
    }
```